# GoLand IDE not correctly compiling. How to setup correct paths?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, ide, goland

I am trying to setup GoLand correctly to be able to use it with Go.

I'm trying to run the follow simple **HelloWorld** go project.

```
package HelloWorldProject


import "fmt"

func main(){
    fmt.Printf("Hello")

    fmt.Printf("1+1 = ", 1+1)

}
```

This is my console's results:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/jeanmac/go #gosetup
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10/libexec/bin/go build -i -o /private/var/folders/r5/rfwd1cqd4kv8cmh5gh_qxpvm0000gn/T/___Hello /Users/jeanmac/go/src/github.com/jpere547/HelloWorldProject/Hello.go #gosetup

Compilation finished with exit code 0
```

I am on Mac OS and I installed Go using Brew.

Results of `brew info go`:

```
go: stable 1.10 (bottled), HEAD
Open source programming language to build simple/reliable/efficient software
https://golang.org
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10 (8,150 files, 336.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-03-22 at 19:38:29
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/go.rb
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.8 ✔
==> Options
--without-cgo
    Build without cgo (also disables race detector)
--without-race
    Build without race detector
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
A valid GOPATH is required to use the `go get` command.
If $GOPATH is not specified, $HOME/go will be used by default:
  https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

You may wish to add the GOROOT-based install location to your PATH:
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
```

The GoLand configurations is below:
**GOROOT**
[image: GOROOT]

**GOPATH**
[image: GOPATH]

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having - the build executed successfully (`Compilation finished with exit code 0`).

Comment: Shouldn't I see `Hello` and `2` be printed to the console?? this is my first time using GoLang

Comment: Looks like you're just building it. In order to see that output you would have to actually run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do *go build something.go* or *go isntall something.go* that only builds/installs the go package to give you an executable. You will need to run that executable.

The easiest way to run simple Golang programs is simply use *go run something.go* that will run your go file.

As long as your GOPATH is correctly set it should work

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are trying to run a non main package. Specifically, instead of `package HelloWorldProject`, you should use `package main`. After that the IDE will be able to not only build but also run the package.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change the package name instead of main

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in configuration to run after build. I think you are missing to set it's configuration.Steps:
1. Go to Run
2. Select "Edit configuration"
3. Select the check-box below output directory field specifying "Run after build".